# SFTP through JAVA slow downs transfer rate?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to SFTP a file from a server using JSCH in java. Though I succeeded in doing that, I notice a drastic slow down in my performance (transfer rate) than compared to, doing the same operation directly through my PUTTY.

At present, I used **channel.get(src,dst)** to get the file from server

Any reason or solution would be of great help!

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
public class SFTPExample {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String srcFile=fl.getSrcFile();
    String tarFile=f1.getTarFile();                
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFilename);
    Session session = jsch.getSession(config.getUser(),config.getSftpHost());
    session.setPassword(config.getpassword());
    session.connect(); 
    Channel Channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpchannel=(ChannelSftp) channel;
    sftpChannel.get(srcFile, tarFile);            
    sftpChannel.exit();
    session.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code from your program.

Comment: Here is the code and is there any inbuilt function to capture the transfer rate in my log?

Comment: @Venk were you able to find any solution ?